# How to handle JSON input with Saxon XSLT

Tags: xslt, saxon

Recent Saxon releases contain a command line argument "-json:myfile.json" to input a JSON file.

But how do I implement the XSLT to parse this JSON? I did not find any doc which handles  this directly (without making use of "json-to-xml" or similar).

I only found this: [how to convert json to xml with saxonjs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70416523/how-to-convert-json-to-xml-with-saxonjs)

But this does not help me, because my json starts with an array:

```json
[
  {
    "eid": "2122.5",
    "ecat": "show",
    "day": "1629410400",
    "spcat": "Bühne",
    "time": "19:30",
    "text": "Welle",
    "remarks": "",
    "location": ""
  },
  {
    "eid": "2122.6",
    "ecat": "show",
    "day": "1629496800",
    "spcat": "Bühne",
    "time": "19:30",
    "text": "Welle",
    "remarks": "",
    "location": ""
  }
]
```

By writing an intermediate XSLT using the function "json-to-xml", I can convert this JSON to xml that looks like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<array xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">
   <map>
      <string key="eid">2122.5</string>
      <string key="ecat">show</string>
      <string key="day">1629410400</string>
      <string key="spcat">Bühne</string>
      <string key="time">19:30</string>
      <string key="text">Welle</string>
      <string key="remarks"/>
      <string key="location"/>
   </map>
   <map>
      <string key="eid">2122.6</string>
      <string key="ecat">show</string>
      <string key="day">1629496800</string>
      <string key="spcat">Bühne</string>
      <string key="time">19:30</string>
      <string key="text">Welle</string>
      <string key="remarks"/>
      <string key="location"/>
   </map>
</array>
```

How can I create a template that matches the root item, and how can I call "apply-templates" to trigger another template that handles the items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSON you have shown is an array so it will be mapped to the XPath/XSLT XDM type `array(*)`, or, in your case, `array(map(xs:string, xs:string))`. To match on that use e.g. `<xsl:template match=".[. instance of array(*)]">..</xsl:template>` or e.g. `<xsl:template match=".[. instance of array(map(xs:string, xs:string))]">..</xsl:template>`.

More complete example would be online at the [fiddle](https://martin-honnen.github.io/xslt3fiddle/?xslt=%3C%3Fxml%20version%3D%221.0%22%20encoding%3D%22utf-8%22%3F%3E%0D%0A%3Cxsl%3Astylesheet%20xmlns%3Axsl%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2FXSL%2FTransform%22%0D%0A%20%20version%3D%223.0%22%0D%0A%20%20xmlns%3Axs%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2001%2FXMLSchema%22%0D%0A%20%20xmlns%3Amap%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2005%2Fxpath-functions%2Fmap%22%0D%0A%20%20exclude-result-prefixes%3D%22%23all%22%0D%0A%20%20expand-text%3D%22yes%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Aoutput%20method%3D%22xml%22%20indent%3D%22yes%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Atemplate%20match%3D%22.%5B.%20instance%20of%20array%28map%28xs%3Astring%2C%20xs%3Astring%29%29%5D%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Citems%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Aapply-templates%20select%3D%22%3F*%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fitems%3E%0D%0A%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Atemplate%3E%0D%0A%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Atemplate%20match%3D%22.%5B.%20instance%20of%20map%28xs%3Astring%2C%20xs%3Astring%29%5D%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Avariable%20name%3D%22map%22%20select%3D%22.%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Citem%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Aiterate%20select%3D%22map%3Akeys%28.%29%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cvalue%20key%3D%22%7B.%7D%22%3E%7B%24map%28.%29%7D%3C%2Fvalue%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Aiterate%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fitem%3E%0D%0A%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Atemplate%3E%0D%0A%20%20%0D%0A%3C%2Fxsl%3Astylesheet%3E%0D%0A&input=%5B%0D%0A%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%22eid%22%3A%20%222122.5%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%22ecat%22%3A%20%22show%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%22day%22%3A%20%221629410400%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%22spcat%22%3A%20%22B%C3%BChne%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%22time%22%3A%20%2219%3A30%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%22text%22%3A%20%22Welle%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%22remarks%22%3A%20%22%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%22location%22%3A%20%22%22%0D%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%22eid%22%3A%20%222122.6%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%22ecat%22%3A%20%22show%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%22day%22%3A%20%221629496800%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%22spcat%22%3A%20%22B%C3%BChne%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%22time%22%3A%20%2219%3A30%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%22text%22%3A%20%22Welle%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%22remarks%22%3A%20%22%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%22location%22%3A%20%22%22%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%5D&input-type=JSON), doing:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="3.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:map="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map"
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
  expand-text="yes">
  
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match=".[. instance of array(map(xs:string, xs:string))]">
    <items>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="?*"/>
    </items>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match=".[. instance of map(xs:string, xs:string)]">
    <xsl:variable name="map" select="."/>
    <item>
      <xsl:iterate select="map:keys(.)">
        <value key="{.}">{$map(.)}</value>
      </xsl:iterate>      
    </item>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

As [for grouping](https://martin-honnen.github.io/xslt3fiddle/?xslt=%3C%3Fxml%20version%3D%221.0%22%20encoding%3D%22utf-8%22%3F%3E%0D%0A%3Cxsl%3Astylesheet%20xmlns%3Axsl%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2FXSL%2FTransform%22%0D%0A%20%20version%3D%223.0%22%0D%0A%20%20xmlns%3Axs%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2001%2FXMLSchema%22%0D%0A%20%20xmlns%3Amap%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2005%2Fxpath-functions%2Fmap%22%0D%0A%20%20exclude-result-prefixes%3D%22%23all%22%0D%0A%20%20expand-text%3D%22yes%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Aoutput%20method%3D%22xml%22%20indent%3D%22yes%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Atemplate%20match%3D%22.%5B.%20instance%20of%20array%28map%28xs%3Astring%2C%20xs%3Astring%29%29%5D%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Citems%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Afor-each-group%20select%3D%22%3F*%22%20group-by%3D%22%3Ftext%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cgroup%20name%3D%22%7Bcurrent-grouping-key%28%29%7D%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Aapply-templates%20select%3D%22current-group%28%29%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fgroup%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Afor-each-group%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fitems%3E%0D%0A%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Atemplate%3E%0D%0A%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Atemplate%20match%3D%22.%5B.%20instance%20of%20map%28xs%3Astring%2C%20xs%3Astring%29%5D%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Avariable%20name%3D%22map%22%20select%3D%22.%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Citem%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Aiterate%20select%3D%22map%3Akeys%28.%29%5Bnot%28.%20%3D%20current-grouping-key%28%29%29%5D%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cvalue%20key%3D%22%7B.%7D%22%3E%7B%24map%28.%29%7D%3C%2Fvalue%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Aiterate%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fitem%3E%0D%0A%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Atemplate%3E%0D%0A%20%20%0D%0A%3C%2Fxsl%3Astylesheet%3E%0D%0A&input=%5B%0D%0A%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%22eid%22%3A%20%222122.5%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%22ecat%22%3A%20%22show%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%22day%22%3A%20%221629410400%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%22spcat%22%3A%20%22B%C3%BChne%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%22time%22%3A%20%2219%3A30%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%22text%22%3A%20%22Welle%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%22remarks%22%3A%20%22%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%22location%22%3A%20%22%22%0D%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%22eid%22%3A%20%222122.6%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%22ecat%22%3A%20%22show%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%22day%22%3A%20%221629496800%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%22spcat%22%3A%20%22B%C3%BChne%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%22time%22%3A%20%2219%3A30%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%22text%22%3A%20%22Welle%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%22remarks%22%3A%20%22%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%22location%22%3A%20%22%22%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%5D&input-type=JSON):

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="3.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:map="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map"
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
  expand-text="yes">
  
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match=".[. instance of array(map(xs:string, xs:string))]">
    <items>
      <xsl:for-each-group select="?*" group-by="?text">
        <group name="{current-grouping-key()}">
          <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
        </group>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
    </items>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match=".[. instance of map(xs:string, xs:string)]">
    <xsl:variable name="map" select="."/>
    <item>
      <xsl:iterate select="map:keys(.)[not(. = current-grouping-key())]">
        <value key="{.}">{$map(.)}</value>
      </xsl:iterate>      
    </item>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Note also, for future reference, that there is a proposal to allow the match pattern to be written as `match="array(map(s:string, xs:string))"`.

Comment: Great, this works. Is there any doc that could point me to the correct syntax (or a tutorial on how to parse JSON)? I have to admit that I don't understand all those curly brackets ;-).

In my real sample, I would have to use `for-each-group` in the next step to group over the field "text". How could this  be done?

But in the end, I think I will switch to a two-step process: first convert json to xml, then use a "classic" XSLT to process the xml. Reason: the "-json" command line argument is only supported in the Java parser HE, but not in the .NET version...

Comment: @wknauf, the .NET Saxon HE 10 release, like the Java HE 10 release, doesn't have the the `-json` command line option, as it was newly introduced in Saxon 11, I think. For .NET that means currently, SaxonCS from Saxonica and .NET 5 or 6, or, as I have managed to cross-compile Saxon HE 11.4 Java to .NET 6, or you could, if you have the .NET 6 SDK installed, try my recently release dotnet tool https://www.nuget.org/packages/SaxonHE11NetXslt/11.4.0-alpha1 which runs Saxon 11.4 HE within .NET 6 as a command line tool/app (with the `-json` option). As for the grouping, raise a new question on that.

Comment: The mapping of JSON to XDM is of course explained in the XPath 3.1 spec or in tutorials on XPath 3.1, like https://www.altova.com/training/xpath3.